# How to add chess diagram \xskakloop in different frame LaTeX beamer?

Tags: beamer, chess, chessboard

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[LSB2,LSBC4,T1]{fontenc} % use fontenc before chessboard
\usepackage{skak,xskak,chessboard,texmate}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\makeatletter
\providecommand\xskak@beforecomment{} %ups a bug, definition is missing
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newcommand\getmovestyle[1]{%
\ifthenelse
{\equal{#1}{N}}%knight move
{\def\mymovestyle{[clockwise=false,style=knight]curvemove}}%
{\ifthenelse
{\equal{#1}{}}% castling
{\def\mymovestyle{curvemove}}%
{\def\mymovestyle{straightmove}}}}%

\begin{frame}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1. e4 d5}\\  
\setchessboard{boardfontsize=19.7pt,labelfontsize=12pt,labelfont=\rmfamily,moverstyle=circle,restorefen=current}

 \setboardfontcolors{blackfieldmask=green!60}
 \xskakloop{%
 \getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
 \chessboard[boardfontencoding=LSBC4,  pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50, markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,     coloremph, color=red!50, markstyle=circle, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
\xskakget{opennr}
\xskakget{lan}
\xskakget{nag} 
\par            
 }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I typeset the chess diagrams in sequence using \xskakloop it gets moved down rather embedding to the different frames in LaTeX beamer.

[image]

Comment: you are missing the `\only<\arabic{chessmoves}>` for the overlays, see the example at page 54 of the xskak documentation.

Comment: Did the above comment solve your question ?

Comment: @BambOo I tried hard but could not understand how to use \only<\arabic{chessmoves}>,  to my code, I read page 54 of xskak package documentation, but could not accomplish, that might be way beyond my knowledge but I thank Ulrike Fisher for his kindness and support.

Comment: I believe you are mising multiple steps of that example , the `\only` but also `\newcounter` and `\refstepcounter`. I managed to make it somewhat work, but I know about nothing of this package, really compare your code and the example line per line. I am sure you will improve your code and Ilrike Fischer will be able to provide additional help.

Comment: @BambOo could you share your result? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I deleted this file, but I am convinced you can manage, I very much started from your script then compared it with the example Ulrike Fischer mentions. You just have to be very careful.

Comment: @BambOo thank you.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer could you get me the snippets of the corrections to incorporate in my primal code?. I tried hard but could not succeed. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[LSB2,LSBC4,T1]{fontenc} % use fontenc before chessboard
\usepackage{skak,xskak,chessboard,texmate}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\makeatletter
\providecommand\xskak@beforecomment{} %ups a bug, definition is missing
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newcommand\getmovestyle[1]{%
  \ifthenelse
    {\equal{#1}{N}}%knight move
    {\def\mymovestyle{[clockwise=false,style=knight]curvemove}}%
    {\ifthenelse
      {\equal{#1}{}}% castling
      {\def\mymovestyle{curvemove}}%
      {\def\mymovestyle{straightmove}}}}%
\newcounter{chessmoves} %<--------------------

\begin{frame}
  \newchessgame
  \mainline{1. e4 d5}\\
  \setchessboard{
    boardfontsize=19.7pt,
    labelfontsize=12pt,
    labelfont=\rmfamily,
    moverstyle=circle,
    restorefen=current
  }

  \setboardfontcolors{blackfieldmask=green!60}
  \setcounter{chessmoves}{0}%
  \xskakloop{%
    \getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
    \refstepcounter{chessmoves}% <----------------
    \only<\arabic{chessmoves}>{% <----------------
      \chessboard[
          boardfontencoding=LSBC4,
          pgfstyle=\mymovestyle,
          color=blue!50,
          markmoves=\xskakget{move},
          pgfshortenend=0.3em,
          arrow=to,
          coloremph,
          color=red!50,
          markstyle=circle,
          markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
          emphfields=\xskakget{moveto},
          setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}
      ]\\
      \xskakget{opennr}
      \xskakget{lan}
      \xskakget{nag}
      \par
    }%<----------------------------
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ulrike Fischer. Thank you very much. It works perfectly fine.